# Insert part of Values from Column A into Column B within same table

Tags: sql-server

I have a requirement to insert data from **Column A** to **Column B**.

**Column A** sample values:

```
CustomerDB_2016_12_12_203001_9284029
CustomerDB_2016-12_11_203005_8572784
CustomerDB_2016-12_10_203353_5347358
```

and so on

**Column B** is blank

I need **Column B** to store values as below (which are derived from **Column A**)

```
2016-12-12
2016-12-11
2016-12-10
```

and so on

Would this be possible in SQL server?

Thanks.

Comment: Is the format of ColumnA fixed?  Does the date always start at character 12 and end at 21?

Comment: Yes it is fixed. Start at 12 and end at 21

Answer (score 5):

An [update query](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx) can do this:

```
UPDATE
    YourTableName
SET
    ColumnB = CAST(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(ColumnA, 12, 10), '_', '-') AS DATE)
;
```

Another approach is to use a [computed column](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms188300.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

```
DECLARE @Sample TABLE 
    (
        ColumnA VARCHAR(255),
        ColumnB AS CAST(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(ColumnA, 12, 10), '_', '-') AS DATE)
    )
;

INSERT INTO @Sample
    (
        ColumnA
    )
VALUES
    ('CustomerDB_2016_12_12_203001_9284029'),
    ('CustomerDB_2016-12_11_203005_8572784'),
    ('CustomerDB_2016-12_10_203353_5347358')
;
```

Both methods return:

```
ColumnA                                 ColumnB
CustomerDB_2016_12_12_203001_9284029    2016-12-12
CustomerDB_2016-12_11_203005_8572784    2016-12-11
CustomerDB_2016-12_10_203353_5347358    2016-12-10
```

If you want to keep two columns in sync I'd recommend using a computed column.  Otherwise go with the update.

I've used [cast](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms187928.aspx) to explicitly set the returned datatype.

I've used [replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms186862.aspx) to reformat the dates.  YYYY-MM_DD becomes YYYY-MM-DD.  The 2nd format can be directly converted from a string to a date.  The first cannot.

I've used [substring](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to extract 10 characters, starting from position 12.

**EDIT**

Trying to extract one value from another is often quite tricky.  In this case, there are several different formats to contend with.

This update query uses a series of [replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms186862.aspx) functions to remove CustomerDb, Backup, underscores and dashes from ColumnA.  What is left should be a string that starts YYYYMMDD.  This value is extracted and converted to a date.

```
-- Each replace strips away unrequired characters,
-- leaving us with a string in the format YYYYMMDD.
UPDATE
    @Sample
SET
    ColumnB = CAST(LEFT(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(ColumnA, 'CustomerDB', ''), '_', ''), '-', ''), 'BACKUP', ''), 8) AS DATE) 
;
```

There are better approaches for this problem.  However this solution is easier to edit and extend.

Comment: Thanks. when I used Update query I ma getting below error Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 11
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: The error is telling you that some of the records do not follow the fixed format.  You can find them by running this query: `SELECT * FROM YouTableName WHERE ISDATE(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(ColumnA, 12, 10), '_', '-')) = 0`.  This query uses the [IsDate function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187347.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to find strings that do not look like dates.

Comment: there are some of old file names like these CustomerDB_2015_05_31_2300. how can I get date from these type of file names. please suggest. sorry I should have add this in my first post

Comment: `CustomerDB_2015_05_31_2300` should be fine.  The date portion still starts at character 12, and then continues for 10 characters.  May has 31 days.  Suspect this isn't the record that is causing you trouble.

Comment: Sorry. There are 40 file names like these CustomerDB_201501312300. I think these are creating problems. how to fix these?

Comment: Upper and lower case isn't an issue.  But _backup_ is.  The key point here is the date does not begin at the 12th character.  Is this a one-off update?  Or are you building an ongoing process?

Comment: It is on going process. Is it possible?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130611/discussion-between-destination-data-and-amelia).